# Picker In iOS App

Tags: ios

How to create a view controller that is used as a picker? It shows up from the bottom of a screen over the current context, and covers just a part of the screen. After a value is picked, it is passed back to a view controller that presented the picker in iOS.

Comment: UIPickerView: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipickerview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in Objective C:

```
    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"Thank you for coming here" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
            UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action){
//define your custom action here or data passing here               
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            }];
            [alert addAction:okAction];
            [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following useful library :

https://github.com/madjid/MMPickerView

**Code snippet**

```
NSArray *strings = @[@"This", @"is", @"just", @"an array", @"of strings."];

  [MMPickerView showPickerViewInView:self.view
                         withStrings:strings
                         withOptions:nil
                          completion:^(NSString *selectedString) {
                            //selectedString is the return value which you can use as you wish
                            self.label.text = selectedString;
  }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a UIViewController and Design as You Want.. Give that View Controller a Stroyboard ID...
add the following code in picker view controller Class

```
var mainVC : YourSendingClassName!
```

when user didSelectRowAtIndexPath..

```
   call self.dismiss(true , completion { 
self.mainVC.userPickedValue(theValueYouWannaPass)
})
```

now in your sender class if you wanna use a button create an Action from it... according to your requirement the button should be at bottom..

add the following code in Button Action

```
   let sliderViewController =  storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourStoryBoard ID") as! YourPickerClass
        sliderViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
     //set width and height as you need   
        sliderViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 253, height: 160)
        sliderViewController.mainVC = self

        let popoverMenuViewController = sliderViewController.popoverPresentationController
        popoverMenuViewController?.permittedArrowDirections = .down
        popoverMenuViewController?.delegate = self
        popoverMenuViewController?.sourceView = sender
        popoverMenuViewController?.sourceRect = sender.frame
        present(sliderViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

after the action create a function

```
  func userPickedValue(value : YourDataype) {
// Do something with received value
}
```